# Using find returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

After several days, suddenly this foundation of my project breaks and I have absolutely no idea why. If someone has any insight as to what's going on here, I would love to know.

I am saving data for line segments to localStorage, using the following code to pull it from storage and pass it to the load method to display it on a canvas.

```
    const graphString = localStorage.getItem('graph');
    const graphInfo = graphString ? JSON.parse(graphString) : null;
    const graph = graphInfo ? Graph.load(graphInfo) : new Graph();
```

then in graph.js, perform the logic to handle the serialization and reintroduce contextual relationships between the points and line segments.

```
    class Graph {
      constructor(points = [], segments = []) {
        this.points = points;
        this.segments = segments;
      }

      static load(info) {
        const points = info.points.map((i) => new Point(i.x, i.y));
        console.log('Points:', points);

        const segments = info.segments.map((i) => {
            const p1 = points.find((p) => p.equals(i.p1));
            const p2 = points.find((p) => p.equals(i.p2));

            console.log('i.p1:', i.p1, 'Found p1:', p1);
            console.log('i.p2:', i.p2, 'Found p2:', p2);

            return new Segment(p1, p2);
        });

        console.log('Segments:', segments);

        return new Graph(points, segments);
      }
    ...snip...

    equals(point) {
      return this.x === point.x && this.y === point.y;
    }
```

the data from localStorage, passed as parameter "info"

```
    Points: (2) [Point, Point]
      0: Point {x: 203, y: 413}
      1: Point {x: 199, y: 202}
```

this is the output from the console logs

```
    i.p1: {x: 316, y: 414} Found p1: undefined
    i.p2: {x: 203, y: 413} Found p2: Point {x: 203, y: 413}
    i.p1: {x: 203, y: 413} Found p1: Point {x: 203, y: 413}
    i.p2: {x: 199, y: 202} Found p2: Point {x: 199, y: 202}

    Segments:(2) [Segment, Segment]
      0: Segment {p1: undefined, p2: Point}
      1: Segment {p1: Point, p2: Point}
```

Does anyone have some insight as to why this happening?

I am a bit beside myself why this suddenly breaks after several days with no explanation.

Currently I am exploring other options to access the data without using find().